# Creating stats out of array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "date":"20/11/2014",
    "time":"17.54.39",
    "car":"369",
    "driver":"Jenny",
    "from":"Luna House",
    "destination":"James Hotel",
    "pax":"3",
    "comment":"",
    "commenttime":"",
    "arrival":"17.54.45",
    "inserted":true,
    "cancelled":"",
    "duration":"00:00:06"
  },
  {
    "date":"23/11/2014",
    "time":"10.54.39",
    "car":"210",
    "driver":"David",
    "from":"Office",
    "destination":"Airport",
    "pax":"3",
    "comment":"",
    "commenttime":"",
    "arrival":"11.01.45",
    "inserted":true,
    "cancelled":"",
    "duration":"00:07:06"
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is to be able to provide stats out of the array of data. Something like this:

[image]

Every object of the array is a trip, car is "car:code" and Time on the road is the sum of all "duration:"12:34:56" (being this a momentJS object).

So far I've been able to create an object that lists all unique months using the following code:

```
var monthDict = {};

angular.forEach($scope.recordlist, function(record) {
  var month = moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY');
  monthDict[month] = monthDict[month] || [];
  monthDict[month].push(record);
});

for (record in monthDict) {     
    var month = record;        
    for (item in monthDict[record]) {
        monthDict[record][item]['month'] = month;        
    }
};

$scope.monthlist = monthDict;
```

[image]

The problem is that I think that to accomplish what I need I have to extract the list of unique cars and drivers from every month array and push it back in.

That's the structure I think I might need:

```
November: {
    Trips: [
        Object 1 {}
        Object 2 {}
    ]
    Cars: [
        369 [
            Object 1 {}
        ] 
        210 [
            Object 1 {}
        ] 
    ]
    Drivers: [
        Jenny [
            Object 1 {}
            Object 2 {}
        ],
        Mango [
            Object 1 {}
            Object 2 {}
        ]
    ]
}
```

So basically, make an object for every unique month, and then for each month, make an array for each unique car and one for each unique driver.

Any tips on how to get there? I'm fearing that this is a bit too advanced for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) it's easier. This would be a way of doing it:

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello AngularJS!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      {{hello}}
      <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
      <pre>{{data2 | json}}</pre>

      <div ng-repeat="(monthName, monthValue) in data2">
        <p class="month-header">{{monthName}}</p>
        <table ng-repeat="(groupName, groupValue) in monthValue">
          <tr>
            <th>{{groupName}}</th>
            <th>Trips</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="(tripName, tripValue) in groupValue">
            <td>{{tripName}}</td>
            <td>{{tripValue.trips}}</td>
            <td>{{tripValue.duration}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
  var dataByMonth = _.groupBy($scope.data, function(record) { return moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY'); });
  console.log(dataByMonth);
  dataByMonth = _.mapValues(dataByMonth, function(month) {
   var obj = {};
   obj.Cars = _.groupBy(month, 'car');
   obj.Drivers = _.groupBy(month, 'driver');

   _.each(obj, function(groupsValue, groupKey) {
      obj[groupKey] = _.mapValues(groupsValue, function(groupValue) {
         return _.reduce(groupValue, function(sum, trip) {
           sum['trips']++;
         //addDuration(sum.duration, car.duration); 
         return sum;
         }, {trips: 0, duration: ''})
       });
   })

   return obj;
  });
 console.log(dataByMonth);
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3sAd2z?p=preview)