# Real time sync update with LoDash and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm building an AngularJS App where I add records in the form of objects into an array.

I've managed to get stats out of this data using LoDash (you can see the pertinent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078776/creating-stats-out-of-array-with-angularjs))
but being a SPA I need the stats to update as I add records into the array (`$scope.recordlist`), and so far they only do when I reload the page.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
var dataByMonth = _.groupBy($scope.recordlist, function(record) { 
    return moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY'); 
});

dataByMonth = _.mapValues(dataByMonth, function(month) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.Cars = _.groupBy(month, 'car');
    obj.Drivers = _.groupBy(month, 'driver');

    _.each(obj, function(groupsValue, groupKey) {
        obj[groupKey] = _.mapValues(groupsValue, function(groupValue) {
            return _.reduce(groupValue, function(sum, trip) {
                sum['trips']++;
                sum['duration']+= moment.utc(trip.duration, 'HH:mm:ss');
                sum['total'] = moment.utc(sum.duration). format('HH:mm:ss')
                //addDuration(sum.duration, car.duration); 
                return sum;
            }, {trips: 0, duration: 0, total:0})
        });
    })

    return obj;
});

$scope.statistics = dataByMonth;
```

What did I miss?

Comment: I doubt that Lodash is a factor at all in your problem. If `$scope.statistics` is set to a correct value upon reloading, the probable issue is how you are using Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is making a few assumptions, but should do what you want. Basically wrap your code in a function and then `$watch` `$scope.recordlist` for changes which calls your function when it does.

```
$scope.refreshStats = function() {
    var dataByMonth = _.groupBy($scope.recordlist, function(record) { 
        return moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY'); 
    });

    dataByMonth = _.mapValues(dataByMonth, function(month) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.Cars = _.groupBy(month, 'car');
        obj.Drivers = _.groupBy(month, 'driver');

        _.each(obj, function(groupsValue, groupKey) {
        obj[groupKey] = _.mapValues(groupsValue, function(groupValue) {
            return _.reduce(groupValue, function(sum, trip) {
                sum['trips']++;
                sum['duration']+= moment.utc(trip.duration, 'HH:mm:ss');
                sum['total'] = moment.utc(sum.duration). format('HH:mm:ss')
                //addDuration(sum.duration, car.duration); 
                return sum;
            }, {trips: 0, duration: 0, total:0})
        });
        })

        return obj;
    });

    $scope.statistics = dataByMonth;
};

$scope.refreshStats(); // for init onload

$scope.$watch('recordlist', $scope.refreshStats, true); // for handling updates w/o reload
```